# A bigger loop in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, folding

I'm using Scala to create a program, but am hitting a wall with how many iterations the loop can do. I'm still quite new when it comes to functional programming and programming in Scala, but this is what I have at the moment:

```
val s = Range(1, 999999999).view.foldLeft(0)(_ + _ / whatever);
```

But i can't get the loop say a few orders of magnitude bigger than 999999999, say as in the max value of a long. I know i could use a for loop, but i cant see a fold option with that.

Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've found, Seqs cannot contain more than Int.MaxValue elements. Until this [feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9888706/why-is-the-scala-for-loop-and-internals-numericrange-restricted-to-int-size-an) is fixed, don't use a Seq. You can

1) use a while-loop

2) use a [for-loop without a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352310/for-loop-in-scala-without-sequence)

but with these ways you can't use the methods of Scala collections like `foldLeft` in your example.

So what you need is an `Iterator`. e.g.

```
def bigIterator(start: BigInt, end: BigInt, step: BigInt = 1) = 
  Iterator.iterate(start)(_ + step).takeWhile(_ <= end)
```

then

```
bigIterator(0, BigInt("3000000000")).foldLeft(BigInt(0))(_ + _)
```

etc will work. Note: if you don't need the full range of `BigInt`, use `Long` instead as it's significantly faster.

Comment: This solved my problem. I am only using long's at the mo, but may go upto bigdecimal, thanks ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
(BigInt(1) to BigInt(999999999)).view.foldLeft(BigInt(0))(_ + _ / whatever)
```

or something like

```
BigInt("89893798138989379873")
```

if you bring enough time with you.

For example:

```
scala> (BigInt(0) to BigInt("2000000000000000") by BigInt("2000000000")).view.foldLeft(BigInt(0))(_ + _)
res: scala.math.BigInt = 1000001000000000000000
```

Comment: Can you explain what this part is doing: 'by BigInt("2000000000")' ? thanks

Comment: `by` specifies the step size.

Comment: This works fine in giving my the same iterations as before: (BigDecimal("1") to BigDecimal("999999999") by BigDecimal("2")), where a step size of 2 is what i'm after, but if i put just one more 9 in there it will give this error: 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 1 to 9999999999 by 2: seqs cannot contain more than Int.MaxValue elements.

Comment: ^ Yea was just about to say this: this doesn't work without the `by` clause, for example `BigInt(1) to BigInt("100000000000")` throws an exception. So you're still limited to Int.MaxValue iterations.

Comment: Yeah, was really hoping there was a way to use say a long or ulong with a step size of 2 :( but thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Sorry, I don’t know if there is a built-in method which may help you with this but you can of course easily write your own tail-recursive `rangeFoldLeft` function if you need to use a larger range.